# MongoDB group and sort by key

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with data like:

```
{
    "_id" : "100",
    "deleted" : false,
    "alphanumericKey" : "s",
    "sortName" : "stackoverflow",
     "name" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "Stack Overflow",
            "language" : "en"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "101",
    "deleted" : false,
    "alphanumericKey" : "s",
    "sortName" : "something",
     "name" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "Something else with s",
            "language" : "en"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "103",
    "deleted" : false,
    "alphanumericKey" : "x",
    "sortName" : "xerox",
     "name" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "Xerox",
            "language" : "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to run a query, that would group the results by the alphanumeric value of each item and show the entire object under this new key. Also wouldn't hurt, if they would be alphabetically sorted, but that's a nice to have... Anyway in the end would look something like this:

```
{
  "s": [{
      "_id": "101",
      "deleted": false,
      "alphanumericKey": "s",
      "sortName": "something",
      "name": [{
        "value": "Something else with s",
        "language": "en"
      }]
    },
    {
      "_id": "100",
      "deleted": false,
      "alphanumericKey": "s",
      "sortName": "stackoverflow",
      "name": [{
        "value": "Stack Overflow",
        "language": "en"
      }]
    }
  ]
}

{
  x: [{
    "_id": "103",
    "deleted": false,
    "alphanumericKey": "x",
    "sortName": "xerox",
    "name": [{
      "value": "Xerox",
      "language": "en"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what part do you not understand? Show your code attempt within the question please.

Comment: db.getCollection('service').aggregate([{$group: {_id:{$substr: ['$sortName', 0, 1]}}}]) however this only makes the grouping through the "sortName" and I can't get it to show the rest of the fields

Comment: [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricks is to do a $group stage with $$ROOT. Here's the answer :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$alphanumericKey",
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },

  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Will return

```
[
  {
    "_id": "s",
    "docs": [
      {
        "_id": "100",
        "alphanumericKey": "s",
        "deleted": false,
        "name": [
          {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Stack Overflow"
          }
        ],
        "sortName": "stackoverflow"
      },
      {
        "_id": "101",
        "alphanumericKey": "s",
        "deleted": false,
        "name": [
          {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Something else with s"
          }
        ],
        "sortName": "something"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "x",
    "docs": [
      {
        "_id": "103",
        "alphanumericKey": "x",
        "deleted": false,
        "name": [
          {
            "language": "en",
            "value": "Xerox"
          }
        ],
        "sortName": "xerox"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

EDIT : For those who cannot use $$ROOT, (before 2.6), you need to describe wour whole document in $group accumulator stage, e.g. :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$alphanumericKey",
      docs: {
        $push: {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "alphanumericKey": "$alphanumericKey",
          "deleted": "$deleted",
          "name": "$name",
          "sortName": "$sortName"
        }
      }
    },

  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention: Mongo version 2.4.14. And I'm kinda stuck to this version. This will generate an error: "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.",